# element in not clickable(was clickable before)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a `submit` element which is located at the end of the HTML page.
It used to work and even when using a normal `Click()` function and not a `Submit` function is used to be clickable and work as expected(even though the element located at the end of the page and in order to actually see it you have to scroll down).
I'm using the following in order to find the element.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_webdriver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10));
var ContinueToNextPageButton = wait.Until(x => x.FindElement(By.Name("ctl00$cntBody$BtnSend")));
ContinueToNextPageButton.Click();
```

I'm getting an exception that the `element was not clickable at point`

The thing is, if I'm using debbuging, and scrolling down before the `Click()`, then it works well. 
I thought this behave only happens in Native apps.

Comment: Is the button visible and enabled?

Comment: yes it is. as I said, when I scroll down on debugging, and then click, it works.

Comment: Try with elementtobeclickable() expected condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Actions` to move to the element you want to click.

```
Actions action = new Actions(webDriver);
//Lets say controlData is the IWebElement you need to click...
action.MoveToElement(controlData).Perform();
controlData.Click();
```

Hope it helps...